# D3plus is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

I am getting an error while trying to implement a text wrapping capability to the labels in my force layout, saying d3plus is not defined. I have the following lines of code to reference d3 and d3plus:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
```

and the following to call the textwrap method

```
d3plus.textwrap()
  .container(d3.select(".dataLabels"))
  .draw();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your script source to **d3plus** isn't correct.
Instead of

```
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
 <script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script><!-- https: added -->
<script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script><!-- https: added -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: That didn't help. I tried referencing online and also downloading it and calling from the local repository.

Comment: Do you use In Page javascript or additional js file? Make sure to refer the d3plus before you call any function of your own js code.

Comment: Yeah, I have referenced it before calling any function.

Comment: Its working from my side, can you please share your code where you are calling d3 functions?

Answer (score 0):

You're loading in versions 3 and 4 of d3, which might be causing the errors. D3plus currently only supports version 3.